# Fatal error: Interface 'Coinbase\Wallet\Authentication\Authentication' not found

Tags: php, coinbase-api

I am trying to coinbase PHP API, I have downloaded PHP library from GitHub and created an index.php file to start working, below is index codes

```
<?php
require_once('src/Client.php');
require_once('src/Configuration.php');
require_once('src/Authentication/ApiKeyAuthentication.php');
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;

$apiKey="";
$apiSecret="";

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

?>
```

And this is generating below error

> Fatal error: Interface 'Coinbase\Wallet\Authentication\Authentication' not found in /home/exhakduz/api/coinbase-php-master/src/Authentication/ApiKeyAuthentication.php on line 8 
>   I can't find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `composer` instead, and require the `composer` autoloader within your `index.php`. The [docs](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php#installation) suggest to install the library with `composer` as well.

> Install the library using Composer. Please read the Composer
>   Documentation if you are unfamiliar with Composer or dependency
>   managers in general.

#### Composer setup / installation

*Note: All commands below need to be run from the same directory where your index.php is located.*

1. First off you'll need to [download and install composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/1.8.6/composer.phar). The current version available is `1.8.6`. Download this `phar` to the same location as your `index.php` script. Also create a `composer.json` file with `{}` as the contents, `composer` will save your dependencies to this file.
2. Make sure `composer.phar` has execute permissions (if on linux run `chmod +x ./composer.phar`)
3. Run `./composer.phar require coinbase/coinbase`. This should install the dependencies within a `vendor` directory.

Finally, you can require the `autoloader` `composer` generates when installing dependencies, and the missing `Interface` error you are seeing will be resolved.

The `composer.json` file should contain the following (bare minimum):

```
{
    "require": {
        "coinbase/coinbase": "^2.8"
    }
}
```

#### Example using autoloader

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;

$apiKey="";
$apiSecret="";

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);
```

Comment: Tnx for your kind explanation, I am using namecheap shared hosting, I have  no Idea how to use composer in shared hosting (I have ssh access but I never used).in library composer.json file is available  with ["autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Coinbase\\Wallet\\": "src/"] this code, but I couldn’t find any directory/files as vendor/autoloader.php, so when I use requre autoloader insted of other 3 requires its giving error file not found.  I made composer.json file 0777 permission and still same

Comment: You could run the commands locally and FTP them up to your hosting provider.